# Using the same generic foreign key field (KeyId) along with a (Type) field for a single table in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class called Address with the following properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
public int KeyId { get; set; }
public AddressType Type { get; set; }
```

The plan is for AddressType to be an enum of either: Customer, Vendor, or Location and the KeyId to be the Foreign Key from either the Customer, Vendor, or Location.

Is this something that can be done correctly with Entity Framework or should I be making 3 separate classes CustomerAddress, VendorAddress, LocationAddress.

Comment: AddressType represents one or more tables? I mean in db you have only one table with name AddressType

Comment: AddressType is an enum, not a table in the database. Sorry should have specified that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an  entity inheritance structure from a single database table. Can achieve that by using a Table per Type approach

[TBT Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Group the common properties into a "Base" entity, and then use a *discriminator* (in your case the `AddressType`) for specializing the object.

Comment: I think I found a solution specifying the foreign key using Fluent API. I added an Addresses navigation property to each entity. Then for each entity I did the following to specify the foreign key: builder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
                .WithOne(a => a.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.KeyId);

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you have three tables Customer, Vendor, or Location and you want to save Address for each.

Then instead of adding AddressType in Address table, you should include AddressID in each table as Foreign key and must have a Address navigation property in each table.

Comment: I believe you are correct about being able to remove the AddressType field. However, these entities can have many addresses. So I would be adding a List navigation property to each class. Then in Fluent API I believe I would do something like this to specify KeyId as the foreign key:             builder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Addresses)
                .WithOne(a => a.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.KeyId);